# How to force script to close all opened files based on theirs directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, psutil

Is it possible to close opened files based only on theirs directories? I would like to close files with specific extension. If it's not possible, I can close all opened files. My code has become so long that I cannot control the closing of files in the other way. I'm preparing application for external users and I developed "reset" button, but I met a problem with accessing to some folder cause by these files are still opened.

I'm using psutil to get list of all opened files by my .py script.

```
[popenfile(path='C:\\Users\\Jan\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Explorer\\iconcache_48.db', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='D:\\jan\\apka_update\\temp\\17-Z1-20180704_Lk7_156.000-180.000_niepelne\\intersection1B.shp', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='D:\\jan\\apka_update\\temp\\17-Z1-20180704_Lk7_156.000-180.000_niepelne\\intersection1A.dbf', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='D:\\jan\\apka_update\\temp\\17-Z1-20180704_Lk7_156.000-180.000_niepelne\\intersection1A.shp', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\pl-PL\\explorerframe.dll.mui', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='D:\\jan\\apka_update\\temp\\17-Z1-20180704_Lk7_156.000-180.000_niepelne\\polygonSet1B.shp', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='C:\\Users\\Jan\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Explorer\\iconcache_idx.db', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\pl-PL\\user32.dll.mui', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='C:\\Users\\Jan\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Explorer\\thumbcache_idx.db', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='D:\\jan\\apka_update\\temp\\17-Z1-20180704_Lk7_156.000-180.000_niepelne\\intersection1B.shx', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='D:\\jan\\apka_update\\temp\\17-Z1-20180704_Lk7_156.000-180.000_niepelne\\PolygonSet1A.dbf', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='D:\\jan\\apka_update\\temp\\17-Z1-20180704_Lk7_156.000-180.000_niepelne\\obszar_zainteresowania.dbf', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\pl-PL\\dui70.dll.mui', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='D:\\jan\\apka_update\\temp\\17-Z1-20180704_Lk7_156.000-180.000_niepelne\\intersection1B.dbf', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='D:\\jan\\apka_update\\temp\\17-Z1-20180704_Lk7_156.000-180.000_niepelne\\polygonSet1B.dbf', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\pl-PL\\shell32.dll.mui', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\pl-PL\\propsys.dll.mui', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='C:\\Users\\Jan\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Explorer\\thumbcache_96.db', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='D:\\jan\\apka_update\\temp\\17-Z1-20180704_Lk7_156.000-180.000_niepelne\\obszar_zainteresowania.shp', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\pl-PL\\NetworkItemFactory.dll.mui', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\pl-PL\\comdlg32.dll.mui', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\StaticCache.dat', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='C:\\Users\\Jan\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Explorer\\iconcache_256.db', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='D:\\jan\\apka_update\\temp\\17-Z1-20180704_Lk7_156.000-180.000_niepelne\\PolygonSet1A.shp', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\pl-PL\\windows.storage.dll.mui', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='D:\\jan\\apka_update\\temp\\17-Z1-20180704_Lk7_156.000-180.000_niepelne\\intersection1A.shx', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\pl-PL\\mpr.dll.mui', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\pl-PL\\KernelBase.dll.mui', fd=-1),
popenfile(path='C:\\Users\\Jan\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Explorer\\iconcache_16.db', fd=-1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test the directory and the extension using the builtin [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) library, or the nice [path.py](https://pathpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html).

```
for fname in my_files:
    _, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
    dirname = os.path.join(fname, os.pardir)

    if ext=".txt" and dirname ="my_dir":
        # close your file
```

Or, with path.py:

```
for fname in my_files:
    fname = Path(fname)
    if fname.ext == ".txt" and fname.parent == "my_dir":
        # close your file
```

Comment: Thanks for response. My question is how exactly "close my file" ? I know how to extract directories and filenames to files with specific extension, but i dont know how close these files without using for example `f.close()`, because i dont know where i define `f` in my code. You know what i mean?

Comment: I open the same file repeatedly at various stages of my script. When i list all opened files in my .py, there is no information about stage at which file became unclosed.

Answer (score 0):

> My code has become so long that I cannot control the closing of files in the other way.

Then it's time to stop everything and fix your code. Actually, your code SHOULD close each file as soon as it's done with it ([the `with` statement is your friend here](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/maintainability/not_using_with_to_open_files.html)), and I have a hard time thinking of any reason for keeping that many files opened at once anyway.

In all cases: you need to have a reference to a file to close it, period. If you open a file, don't close it and discard the reference to the file then well... too bad.

Ok, there might eventuall be a **very** ugly workaround which would be to replace all `open()` calls with your own version that stores the opened file in some global list. But really, that's only going to make your code worse, so do the right thing: fix your code to properly close files at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
import psutil

## Close open processes matching the path.
pathToClear = "{PATH GOES HERE}"

print(f"...Searching for active processes matching path: '{pathToClear}'")
for proc in psutil.process_iter(['name', 'open_files']):
    for file in proc.info['open_files'] or []:
        if pathToClear in file.path:
            print(f"Found process potentiall process potentially locking path. Killing: '{proc.info['name']}'")
            print("%-5s %-10s %s" % (proc.pid, proc.info['name'][:10], file.path))
            proc.kill()

print("Completed!")
```

Reference:

- https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/